# Activity binds Service with Application context -> service leaks on pressing back after configuration change

Tags: java, android, android-service

I'm having an Activity that is launching more instances of itself on user interaction. This activity binds to a service that maintains a bluetooth connection. Currently this is realized like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    //bind the activity to the service when it is not bound yet.
    if (!this.isBound)
    {
        //Application context, because the Connection shall be kept over configuration change, and the activity will be replaced then.
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), ConnectionService.class);
        bindService(serviceIntent, this.connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        this.isBound = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.connection = (ServiceConnection)getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    }
    this.visible = true;
}

/**
 * Saves the bound state.
 */
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    outState.putBoolean("isBound", this.isBound);
}

/**
 * Loads the bound state.
 */
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inState)
{
    this.isBound = inState.getBoolean("isBound");
}

/**
 * Called by system, gives the current ServiceConnection to the system to be retrieved again after restart.
 */
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return this.connection;
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    //unbind the activity to the service when it is finishing.
    super.onPause();
    this.visible = false;
    if (this.isFinishing() && this.isBound)
    {
        unbindService(this.connection);
        this.isBound = false;
    }
}
```

Now my problem is: When I change the orientation while the app is running, everything is okay unitl i press the back button. Then

```
07-05 12:07:03.039: E/ActivityThread(17850): Activity mm.android.prototype.uilayer.DatapointActivity has leaked ServiceConnection mm.android.prototype.uilayer.DatapointActivity$1@408bcbb8 that was originally bound here  

07-05 12:07:03.039: E/ActivityThread(17850): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity mm.android.prototype.uilayer.DatapointActivity has leaked ServiceConnection mm.android.prototype.uilayer.DatapointActivity$1@408bcbb8 that was originally bound here
```

is written on the Log, and the app crashes in the onPause() Method at the unbind command. I've read the post of Dianne Hackborn in the google forum about the thing, that i can't rely on the ServiceConnection, but i didn't find any solution how to cope with it. Can you help me to get rid of this error and/or explain me why my app behaves like this?

Comment: [Dianne Hackborn forum link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/Nb58dOQ8Xfw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by makeing the ServiceConnection static and reusing it in every instance of myActivity. Also i added a static counter that counts the instances, and unbinds if the last instance closes. This also solves the config change issue:

```
private boolean isBound = false;

private static int bindCount = 0;

// handles the service connection.
protected static ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection(){
// ...
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    //bind the activity to the service when it is not bound yet.
    if (!this.isBound)
    {
        if (bindCount == 0) {
            //Application context, because the Connection shall be kept over configuration change, and the activity will be replaced then.
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), ConnectionService.class);
            bindService(serviceIntent, DatapointActivity.connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            this.isBound = true;
        }
        bindCount++;
        this.isBound = true;
    }
    this.visible = true;
}

/**
 * Saves the bound state.
 */
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    outState.putBoolean("isBound", this.isBound);
}

/**
 * Loads the bound state.
 */
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inState)
{
    this.isBound = inState.getBoolean("isBound");
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    //unbind the activity of the service when it is finishing.
    super.onPause();
    this.visible = false;
    if (this.isFinishing())
    {
        if(bindCount <= 1 && this.isBound )
        {
            unbindService(DatapointActivity.connection);                
        }
        bindCount--;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's cool that you solved it. Having some code as an example could help some unfortunate soul even more.